Im having problems getting beautiful soup to work in vs studio code
It says bs4 module not found.  I tried using pip to install and it says the term pip is not recognized.  I tried to install pip using cmd and the video starts with locating my python version.
C:\Users\Josh>where.exe python
C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

C:\Users\Josh>python --version
The system cannot find the file C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

this is the current problem.  At one point I had gotten vs code to use pip and fixed the problem with bs4 but then was having the problem with it not finding python where it should be.  I had created a new environment and done a bunch of things. So fully uninstalled vs code and all files connected and reinstalled.  I would really appreciate any help before making it a big mess while trying stuff again.
Im following a code course learning how to use beautifulsoap and would like it to work instead of getting errors
Edit: I created a new work environment again and got bs4 and pip working but now get this error
"c:/Users/Josh/Desktop/Programming/100 Days of Code content/Web Development Projects/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/Josh/Desktop/Programming/100 Days of Code content/Web Development Projects/Day 45/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Josh\Desktop\Programming\100 Days of Code content\Web Development Projects\Day 45\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    contents = file.read()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 281: character maps to <undefined

this is my code. the file path is slightly different then the teachers but everything else is the same and I dont understand why im getting so may errors:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("Day 45/website.html") as file:
    contents = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")

print(soup.title)


C:\Users\Josh\AppData is usually a hidden folder.  Try running your cmd window as an administrator.

running as admin does show python version correctly so 1 problem down.  Thank you

Try adding these arguments encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore' to the open() call.

the file path is slightly different then the teachers but everything else is the same Is the teacher also using a Windows computer?

mac but i copied the relative path and pasted it

I didnt see your comment about adding the arguments before but they fixed it!!! thank you soooo much ive been at this for probably 6 hours off an on today

open() can behave a little differently on windows/mac, so that explains why it worked for the teacher.
